# Writing my first C program and I can't get past this dumb bug

Tags: c, scanf

I'm using xCode because I found the debugger to be very useful. So in the debugger I see, after I enter the students name name[0] = \0 no matter what. But then the rest of the name will be correct. For example, if I put John, it will come back saying \0, o, h, n. Help please?

```
        char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
        char department[MAX_DEPT_LENGTH];
        int rank;
        int empty = 0;

        printf("\nPlease enter the students name: ");
        scanf("%s", &name);
        printf("\nPlease enter the students department: ");
        scanf("%s", &department);
        printf("\nPlease enter the students rank: ");
        scanf("%d", &rank);


        strcpy(studentArray[empty].name, name);
        strcpy(studentArray[empty].department, department);
        studentArray[empty].rank = rank;
```

Comment: Could you give the declaration of studentArray as well?

Comment: Off-topic (your issue the fact that you've used `&name` where you should have said `name`), but `scanf` with `%s` is bad times.  You don't get to specify a buffer size, which means a user can enter a string that's longer than your buffer and smash your stack.  There is a non-portable extension `%a` which will allocate the right amount of memory for you but in my opinion it's best to just avoid `scanf`'s crummy interface altogether.

Comment: Are you sure this is all of your code?  Can you post a complete, compilable example that demonstrates the problem?  (I don't have xCode or a Mac, but I failed to reproduce this behavior with a half-dozen combinations of compilers and settings.)

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
    printf("\nPlease enter the students name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("\nPlease enter the students department: ");
    scanf("%s", department);
    printf("\nPlease enter the students rank: ");
    scanf("%d", &rank);
```

Note the absence of ampersands in the first two calls to `scanf`. This is because the compiler implicitly converts `name` and `department` into pointers to the first elements of the respective arrays (`&name[0]`, `&department[0]`) when they are used in an expression (there are expections to this rule, see [here](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html) for details).

Read [this](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/26arraysaspointers.html) for further reference.

Comment: `&rank` was perfectly correct. Besides that, a short explanation for a **beginner** would be appropriate.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Corrected the mistake.

Comment: I like to think about it this way: there are no real arrays, only memory, pointers and offsets. If I was taught this way from the beginning, I'd probably avoid making some silly mistakes in my earlier programs.

Comment: @Grigory Unfortunately, that isn't exactly the case.

Comment: Good that it works for you ... but **there are arrays**, and they're very different to pointers. see [c-faq question 6.3](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html) ... and all other questions in the section 6.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that pointers are equivalent to arrays (although, apparently, it can be concluded so from my answer). It is obvious that pointers and arrays are different, because a pointer is (roughly) a variable that holds some memory address while an array is a certain data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `scanf("%s", name);` instead of `scanf("%s", &name);` (same for `department`).

`scanf` needs a memory address to write to. In case of a string it expects a `char *` and passing a `char[]` is fine in this case (**it is vulnerable to buffer overflows though!**).

However, for your integer - which is not a pointer - you need to pass the *memory address* of the integer, i.e. `&rank` instead of `rank` - which you already did.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables `name` and `department` are character arrays (`char (*)[]`).  When you pass these variables to printf/scanf (or any other function, arrays are passed by reference), their types decay to `TYPE*` (in your case `char*`) and are passed as the memory location of the first element in the array.

When you try to pass the address of the varible (`&name`), you are passing a pointer to that variable's memory location (in your case, this decays to `char(*)[0]`).  This question intrigued me because `name` and `&name` will have the same value, but different types.  Since printf/scanf are defined to receive `char*`, passing char(*)[] results in undefined behavior - some compilers will handle if for you while others won't (VS2010 and maybe earlier versions handle this for you).

I was close, but had some help with this answer (learned a lot): [& operator definition for arrays in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851177/operator-definition-for-arrays-in-c).  If they provide an answer here, I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

The scanf function needs to know the address in memory it needs to read in, so for things like integers

```
scanf("%d", &rank);
```

is correct. But things like name are already addresses (the name of an array is effectively the address of its first element) so instead of :

```
scanf("%s", &name);
```

you want:

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

And similarly for other arrays.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an array;

```
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
```

`name` without an index is a pointer to the first element in the array.

```
name == &name[0]
```

When a function (such as `scanf()`) calls for a `char *` it wants the pointer to the first element.

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

Comment: "`name` without an index is a pointer."  Except when it isn't:  for an array with a length greater than one, `sizeof(name) != sizeof(&name[0])`.  `name` is always an array; it is just implicitly converted to a pointer to its initial element in most cases.

Answer (score -1):

use `scanf("%s", name);`

avoid using &, it's too easy to get wrong.

Comment: When writing to an integer using `&` is perfectly fine. Actually, it's necessary.

Comment: "Avoid using `&`"?  Really?  You won't get very far if you avoid amperands when programming in C.