# & operator definition for arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, standards

A recent question prompted a discussion centering on arrays and pointers.  The question was in reference to `scanf("%s", &name)` vs `scanf("%s", name)`.

For the following code, Microsoft actually resolves this for you in VS2010 (and maybe earlier versions?),

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[30];

    printf("Scan \"name\" - ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Print \"&name\" - %s\n", &name);
    printf("Print \"name\"  - %s\n", name);

    printf("Pointer to &name - %p\n", &name);
    printf("Pointer to name  - %p\n", name);

    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Scan \"&name\" - ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    printf("Print \"&name\" - %s\n", &name);
    printf("Print \"name\"  - %s\n", name);

    printf("Pointer to &name - %p\n", &name);
    printf("Pointer to name  - %p\n", name);

    return 0;
}
```

Is this actually defined in the ANSI C Standard, or is this allowed to be compiler dependent?  Does this work because MS is treating everything as C++?  Please ignore buffer overflow issues for now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both `name` and `&name` should give the same result.  Strictly speaking, only `name` is valid per the C language standard and `&name` results in undefined behavior, so you should definitely use `name`, but in practice both will work.

`name` is an array, so when you use it as an argument to a function (as you do when you pass it to `printf`), it "decays" to a pointer to its initial element (which is a `char*` here).

`&name` gives you the address of the array; this address is the same as the address of the initial element (because there can be no padding bytes before the initial element of an array or between elements in an array), so `&name` and `name` have the same pointer value.

However, they have different types:  `&name` is of type `char (*)[30]` (a pointer to an array of 30 `char`) while `name`, when it decays to a pointer to its initial element, is of type `char*` (a pointer to a `char`, in this case, the initial `char` element of the array `name`).

Since they have the same value and since the `printf` and `scanf` functions reinterpret the argument as a `char*` anyway, there should be no difference whether you pass `name` or `&name`.

Comment: Practically speaking, you're absolutely right. It's probably worth mentioning, however, that officially the mismatch leads to undefined behavior, so it's better to omit it.

Comment: @Jerry:  I think you're right that the results are undefined so I did add a note, though I'd be surprised if there was an implementation where the representations of `&name[0]` and `&name` are different.  Their sizes definitely have to be the same.

Comment: Yup -- like I said, practically speaking it causes no harm.

Comment: This person: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850800/writing-my-first-c-program-and-i-cant-get-past-this-dumb-bug/ was having an issue, and it appears that XCode doesn't resolve the address properly, so that prompted my question about the acutal C Standard.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior described in that question.  The language standard says that you must pass a `char*`, so `&name` is wrong, but I can't imagine that causing problems, especially not when compiling for x86/x64.

Comment: Why would `&name` result in undefined behavior? `%s` requires an argument that is "a pointer to the initial element of a character array...".  Either `name` or `&name` do that, even if they have a different type.

Comment: @Michael:  I think it's formally undefined because the type of the argument (`char(*)[30]`) doesn't match the type required by `%s` (`char*`).  I can't imagine getting different results from `name` and `&name`, though:  the size of both pointer types has to be the same as `sizeof(void)` and I can't think of any reason you'd have the two pointer types represented differently.  Then again, my experience with C is limited to x86/x64/PowerPC, so I have no knowledge of how C works on more exotic platforms.

Comment: @James: what the standard says `%s` requires is what I quoted: "a pointer to the initial element of a character array". It seems to me that a `char (*)[30]` fulfills that requirement.

Comment: @Michael:  Oh; I missed the quote marks.  I think one could split hairs and say that "a pointer to the initial element of an array" is different from "a pointer to the array" because the types are different.  They have to point to the same location, but perhaps they might have different representations (e.g., could an implementation implement pointers to have type tags?).  I can't think of any reason one would want to do this.  You might well be correct and it might well be well-formed and correct.  I'm not 100% convinced that `&name` is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Undefined Behaviour as per the Standard.

The printf conversion specifier `"%p"` expects a `void*`: anything else invokes UB
The printf conversion specifier `"%s"` expects a `char*` that includes a null byte somewhere inside the object pointed to: anything else invokes UB
The scanf conversion specifier `"%s"` expects a `char*` with enough space for the input and an extra null terminating byte: anything else invokes UB

If any implementation defines the behaviour, then it should be ok to use in **that implementation**.

Most often printing a `char*` or a `char(*)[30]` instead of a `void*` with `printf("%p")` results in a UB manifestation that is indistinguishable from the intended behaviour.

Most often printing a `char(*)[30]` instead of a `char*` with `printf("%s")` results in a UB manifestation that is indistinguishable from the intended behaviour.

From what you say, it appears MS manifestation of UB in these cases is the same as intended.

**But it's still Undefined Behaviour.**

Comment: The ever thin line between 'Undefined Behaviour' and 'Implementation Defined Behaviour' - if there is a line at all

Comment: @sehe: If the Standard says it's implementation defined (see, for example, 6.3.2.3/5 in n1256.pdf), then the construct needs to work in a defined way (albeit differently among inplementations) in all implementations. If the Standard says it's undefined (or fails to define the behaviour) there is no need for an implementation to define it -- anything can happen in that case.